# ¿Hay alguna expresión en castellano para el concepto “single-issue politics”?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

La expresión en inglés *single-issue politics* significa, según [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-issue_politics):

> ...political campaigning or political support based on one essential policy area or idea.

("hacer campaña política o [la obtención de] apoyo político basado en una idea política esencial"). *The Concise Oxford Dictionary of Politics* amplía diciendo:

> This is often characterized by a preoccupation with the particular issue to the exclusion of all others, an intensity of feeling about the issue, and a willingness to devote considerable resources of time and money to its pursuit. Because the attachment to the issue is often based on moral grounds, there is a reluctance to compromise. Typical examples of single issue politics are abortion, the debate about hunting with dogs and animal protection issues more generally, and the care of sufferers from specific diseases. Issues of this kind are often associated with single issue pressure groups.

(Resumiendo, esta clase de política "se caracteriza por una preocupación con [un] asunto en particular con exclusión de todos los otros.") Un ejemplo notable son los partidos o movimientos políticos que se fundan exclusivamente para oponerse al derecho al aborto legal o para ocuparse de un puñado de temas relacionados con la ecología.

También se utilizan *single-issue voter* para un votante que (en teoría) decide su voto a un candidato exclusivamente por la postura manifestada por éste ante el asunto particular que interesa.

¿Hay alguna expresión en castellano que traduzca adecuadamente este concepto? Como mínimo busco una expresión que traduzca la idea sin demasiada ambigüedad (de manera que alguien que la escucha y que tiene algo de idea de política pueda captarla sin explicaciones); como máximo, una frase que sea usada en estudios académicos sobre el tema y ya sea reconocida como la forma estándar de traducir *single-issue politics*.

P.D. A pedido y porque es una buena práctica para la mejor comprensión, añado unos ejemplos de cómo usaría estas frases:

- "La estrategia de hacer política _______ [single-issue politics] puede dar réditos sólo en estos tiempos de votantes desilusionados con los partidos mayoritarios."
- "Es difícil saber qué piensan estos votantes _______ [single-issue voters] que pueden lograr al votar a un candidato sin chance alguna, sólo de manera testimonial."
- "El sentido común dicta que un partido _______ [single-issue party] debería concentrarse en proponer candidatos al Poder Legislativo, donde una cantidad relativamente pequeña de votos le garantizaría al menos un escaño."

Comment: Nos das una frase que muestre cómo quieres usar el término, por favor.  Puedes poner ______ donde va el término.  Gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Desconozco si en círculos puramente políticos se usa algún otro término más específico, pero uno que te puede valer y que a veces se utiliza para hablar de partidos cuya política gira alrededor de un único punto es: [**monotemático**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=PiCjEKM).

> La proliferación de partidos y programas monotemáticos y su constante incorporación al sistema político mayoritario tuvieron un especial coste para las organizaciones de izquierda tradicionales.
>   <sub>Tony Judt, *Postguerra*. (Extraído de [este artículo de El Confidencial](https://blogs.elconfidencial.com/espana/interiores/2014-02-03/la-fragmentacion-de-los-partidos-y-la-falta-de-un-liderazgo-de-pais_84014/).)</sub>

> Se entiende aquí por partido monotemático aquel que, con el objetivo de obtener puestos de gobierno –en este caso diputaciones-, constituye su discurso, programa y oferta electoral a partir de la defensa de una causa específica, presentándose como su más fiel abanderado y prometiendo que, -esta vez sí- se legislará en serio a favor de su población meta.
>   <sub>Mariano Salas Naranjo, ["La estafa política de los partidos monotemáticos"](https://ciep.ucr.ac.cr/hablemos-politica/la-estafa-pol%C3%ADtica-de-los-partidos-monotem%C3%A1ticos).</sub>

> Uno de los fenómenos políticos más notables de los últimos años es la emergencia de partidos que podríamos llamar monotemáticos, es decir, que basan su discurso en un único tema, dejando en segundo plano, si no en la ambigüedad, su visión general de la sociedad.
>   <sub>Carlos López Díaz, ["Partidos monotemáticos"](http://archipielagoduda.blogspot.com/2009/01/partidos-monotemticos.html).</sub>

Con eso en mente, la traducción de *single-issue politics* podría ser "políticas monotemáticas" o "**políticas monotema**".

Answer (score 3):

Propongo

> **políticas de agenda única**

o

> **políticas de agenda monotemática**

usando el término (en coincidencia con @walen) para designar la exclusividad de la causa. La expresión puede verse usada [en esta nota](https://eleccionesenalemania.com/2014/12/30/los-cinco-eventos-politicos-mas-relevantes-de-2014-en-alemania/) en la que se señala la persecución de un objetivo único por parte de un partido alemán.

> *Alternativa para Alemania (AfD) estuvo al borde de lograr el 5% en las
>   elecciones federales de 2013 con una **agenda monotemática**: La Unión
>   Europea, y en especial el euro, es perjudicial para Alemania.*

Answer (score 0):

Propongo:

**única propuesta**

En Colombia se usa la palabra "**propuesta**" para aquello que apoyará y/o hará un candidato en caso de ser elegido.

Un ejemplo: **[Propuestas de Iván Duque](https://www.ivanduque.com/propuestas)**

Answer (score -1):

En algún texto de estudios de género he encontrado "**enfoque unitario**" como traducción de single issue.
Espero que sea útil.
Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido/a! Tendrías por casualidad enlaces a alguno de esos textos donde aparece la expresión "enfoque unitario" con este significado?

Comment: Gracias por la contribución Sole, pero esta es prácticamente una respuesta "link only". Aunque "enfoque unitario" puede ser una respuesta válida, con el contenido de esta contribución estoy prácticamente obligado a irme a otro sitio, buscar la definición del término aplicada a esta contexto y algún ejemplo. Esta contribución ganaría mucho si pudiese explicar el término aunque solo fuese un poco (como hacen algunas de las otras respuestas) e incluso demostrarlo con un ejemplo. De lo contrario, esta contribución es más un comentario o sugerencia que una respuesta.